# Android C2DM working if the task is killed

Tags: android, android-c2dm

If a server tries to send a cloud message to a device, but the task is killed somehow (such as advanced task killer), will the message be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You should be using a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in your manifest to receive the C2DM message broadcasts meant for your application when they hit the device.  The messages are sent over a connection that is maintained by Google services and, thus, is independent of whether your app is already running.

Comment: Is there another way to receive C2DM messages? I really would like to know!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no alternative to receive android C2DM.